# How to fix 'Undo Filter' in JS and Jquery (When Searching)

Tags: javascript

I'm Korean Sorry grammatically break :)

I want to make 'Search bar' with 'Category'

For example,
If Category is 'fruit', Of the total data, 'fruit' show.
If After I click 'fruit' category, and search 'tomato', 'tomato' show in 'fruit' category not in 'all'

but this code has some problems.

If I search 'tomato', tomato show in 'all' category not in the 'fruit' category.

Namely, If I search for something, the category is undone.

plz help!

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // click effect and category
    $('.category_item').click(function() {


        $(this).addClass('on').siblings().removeClass('on');



        var category = $(this).attr('id');



        if(category == 'all') {
            $('tr').hide().show();

            /*$('tr').show();*/

        } else {
            $('tr').hide();

            $('.' + category).show();

        }



    }); // click



/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



    //search

    $('.inputSearch').keydown(function(key) {
        var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();



        if(key.keyCode == 13) {
            $("tbody tr").filter(function() {
                $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)

            });

        } // if



    }); // search



})// ready
```

Comment: plz help!! code fences fixed